# Get file name with extension and get only extension

Tags: lua

I have again 2 functions but this time they return either the full file name with extension or just the extension with a dot.

Both actions are so similar that I just copy pasted the code from one and changed 1 character... but at the inside I am cringing because it looks terrible to just copy paste. In addition I am not sure if my way of doing it is good and efficient?

```
-- Return everything until first forward slash starting at the end. http://my.image.com/bla.jpg would return bla.jpg
function GetFileName(url)
  local str = url
  local temp = ""
  local result = ""

  -- Get file name + extension until first forward slash (/) and then break
  for i = str:len(), 1, -1 do
    if str:sub(i,i) ~= "/" then
      temp = temp..str:sub(i,i)
    else
      break
    end
  end

  -- Reverse order of full file name
  for j = temp:len(), 1, -1 do
    result = result..temp:sub(j,j)
  end

  return result
end

-- Get the extension of a string determined by a dot . at the end of the string.
function GetFileExtension(url)
    local str = url
  local temp = ""
  local result = "." -- ! Remove the dot here to ONLY get the extension, eg. jpg without a dot. The dot is added because Download() expects a file type with a dot.

  for i = str:len(), 1, -1 do
    if str:sub(i,i) ~= "." then
      temp = temp..str:sub(i,i)
    else
      break
    end
  end

  -- Reverse order of full file name
  for j = temp:len(), 1, -1 do
    result = result..temp:sub(j,j)
  end

  return result
end
```

Usage:

```
print(GetfileName("http://mypath.to.my.image/image.jpg"))
print(GetFileExtension("http://mypath.to.my.image/image.jpg"))
```

Result:

```
image.jpg
.jpg
```

What would be a better approach or is this as good as it goes? (I highly doubt that. :))

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are doing too much work manually. It's so much easier and more powerful to use pattern matching.

The two functions can be written as one-liners:

```
function GetFileName(url)
  return url:match("^.+/(.+)$")
end

function GetFileExtension(url)
  return url:match("^.+(%..+)$")
end
```

In the patterns, `.+` matches one or more any characters as much as possible (greedy). `/` matches itself, `%.` matches the dot `.`. `^` and `$` are the anchors for beginning and ending of a string respectively.

Comment: `GetFileExtension` would give incorrect result for `http://example.com/path/image_without_extension`

Comment: But would get correct results with: `return GetFileName(url):match("^.+(%..+)$")`

Comment: `GetFileName` doesn't work properly if the name is given without any slashes; you get nil back.

Answer (score 8):

Since you want to get everything from the end, until first `/` or `.` are found; use a lua-pattern.

While Yu Hao's suggested pattern would give you the desired results; you can also use the following:

```
url:match "[^/]+$" -- To match file name
url:match "[^.]+$" -- To match file extension
url:match "([^/]-([^.]+))$" -- To match file name + file extension
```